# Prisma @db.Time(x) - what is x?

Tags: prisma

After running the `npx prisma introspect` in the console, the `startTime` attribute was set to `@db.Time(6)` in my `schema.prisma` file.

```
model Table {
  id           String     @id @default(uuid())
  startTime    DateTime   @map("start_time") @db.Time(6)
}
```

What does `x` mean in `@db.Time(x)` in Prisma schema? [Documentation link](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#postgresql-6)

P.S. I use `PosgreSQL` as database

Comment: how are you sending that time value eg startTime: "12:00:00" like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `x` is the precision to store in the `time` type which can be anything from 0-6. You can read more this [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-time/).

Comment: Thank you! It's shocking how difficult this information was to find.